# Read data from website and paste that data into Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

Here is the code to read the textdata from the website and paste that data into Excel firstcolumn (row by row) (1,1),(2,1),(3,1) vice versa.

```
Function Read(URL)
    Set ie = Wscript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set objFSO = Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

    ie.Navigate(URL) 
    ie.Visible = 1

    Do While ie.Busy
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop

    Data = ie.document.documentElement.innerText 
    MsgBox(Data)

    sp = Split(Data, " ")
    b  = UBound(sp)

    MsgBox(b)

    For i=0 To b
        MsgBox(sp(i))
    Next

    selectexcel = InputBox("Enter the location", _
                  "Location of the excel file(Xls/xlsx)", _
                  "Enter your path here !")

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(selectexcel)
    objExcel.Visible = True

    rowCount = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    colCount = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For i=1 To b Step 1
        For j=1 To 1 Step 1
            objExcel.Cells(i, j).Value = sp(i)
            k = k+1
       Next
    Next       
End Function

Read "https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl"

Set ie = Nothing
```

It reads the textdata from the beginning, but I want to read the textdata from the Value which I would give in the `InputBox`.

Comment: *"but I want to read the textdata from the Value which I would give in the `InputBox`* What are you talking about? The code you posted has only one `InputBox` (the one where the user enters the workbook to open).